# url not accessible within jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, url

We have a JSP file which tries to import a url (html template) via a link pointing to an external resource. When the webpage loads, we see the following error on the logs

> Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://mywebsite-dns.com:990/abc/html/customHTML.html?lang=en

So obviously this is an authentication error, but is it client side or server side authentication issue? I believe the server don't have access to the specified resource. Is that statement right?

**JSP CODE**

```
<c:set var="customHTML" 
           value="${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}${pageContext.request.contextPath}/html/customHTML.html?lang=${locale}" />
    <div id="custom-HTML">     
    <c:import url="${customHTML}" />
    </div>
```

Comment: The error is coming from the server side.  Which is shown by the 401 Unauthorized 
http response code.  Unauthorized really should say Unauthenticated, but that is a different matter.  Can you reach the url you want to c:import via command line tools like wget or curl?  Do you know if you're suppose to supply authentication to the url you're trying to call?  It looks like you're actually trying to call the same server that you're serving the content from anyways, I am not positive, but I believe that there are ways of importing html from other pages without making an external http request.

Comment: @hooknc - thanks for the response. Yes the client has access the url directly through the web browser. But they have some other components in place that resolve the identity management of users while login, somehow the server access  doesn't get resolved properly I guess. The html template resides in the same server but in an external folder. It needs to be imported via a url - legacy code

Comment: When you say user, I am assuming that this is the end user's browser.  The request that you're making with c:import is not from the end user, but from the server itself.  Meaning that the server is a client of itself and the server will have to authenticate just like the end user does.  Yay?

Comment: @hooknc - exactly. That was my initial question. Who is trying to resolve the url? 
End user or Server? C-import means the server needs to resolve it first. 
So they probably need to add server as an authenticated user to access the url.

Comment: Understood now, yes, the server needs to be authenticated like any other client.